# When I Press Back Button(from the stack header) or swipe left to right, ios app crashes

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

When I Press Back Button(In the stack header) or swipe left to right in a physical iPhone device my react native app crashes. The App is working fine in the simulator but not in a physical device.

So, how can I fix this issue?

Here is the code for my main navigator

```
import { themeColor, themeColorLite } from "../styles/common";
import Login from "../views/Login"
import ForgetPass from "../views/forgetPass"
import Registration from "../views/Registration"
import UserDashboard from "../views/user/dashboard"
import ProductDetails from "../views/user/productDetails"
import ShoppingMall from "../views/user/shoppingMalls"
import Shops from "../views/user/shops"
import NormalProducts from "../views/user/normalProducts"
import ShoppingCart from "../views/user/shoppingCart"
import UserProfile from "../views/user/profile"
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer'
import UserDrawerNav from '../views/drawerNav'

const ProductStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  UserDashboard: UserDashboard,
  ProductDetails: ProductDetails,
  ShoppingCart: ShoppingCart,
  ShoppingMall: ShoppingMall,
  Shops: Shops,
  NormalProducts: NormalProducts
})

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    UserDashboard: ProductStackNavigator,
    ShoppingMall: ProductStackNavigator,
    UserProfile: UserProfile
  },
  {
    contentComponent: UserDrawerNav,
    hideStatusBar: true,
    drawerBackgroundColor: 'white',
    overlayColor: themeColorLite,
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#fff',
      activeBackgroundColor: themeColor,
    }
  }, {
  unmountInactiveRoutes: true
}
);

const AuthStack = createSwitchNavigator({ 
  Login: { screen: Login } ,
  Registration: { screen: Registration } ,
  ForgetPass: { screen: ForgetPass }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    App: DrawerNavigator,
    Auth: AuthStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Auth',
  }
));

export default AppContainer;
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ENC",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "ipadAir": "react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPad Air (3rd generation)'",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "iphone11": "react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPhone 11'",
    "cleanStart": "react-native start --reset-cache",
    "link": "react-native link",
    "podInstall": "cd ios && pod install && cd ..",
    "podUpdate": "cd ios && pod update && cd ..",
    "upgradeRN": "react-native upgrade",
    "regenDir": "react-native upgrade --legacy true",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "react": "16.10.1",
    "react-native": "0.61.2",
    "react-native-flip-card": "^3.5.5",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.14.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-photo-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-really-awesome-button": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-tiny-toast": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-webview": "^7.4.0",
    "react-native-xml2js": "^1.0.3",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.5",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.2.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "1.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.10.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

The above code is also available at my gist [here](https://gist.github.com/mashfiqcse13/e90812cf1c042850cd64654a8ae87bf9)

Comment: Please show me the part of the code that has an error when pressed.

Comment: I don't know where is the error. It is fine in ios simulator. But when I run the app from ios testflight in a physical ios device, this happens.

Comment: My words are the code for the part of the collision.

Comment: I really don't know. But I am suspecting that it is happening for react-navigation or react-native-gesture-handler.

Comment: It is only happening during the app run from the app store connect testflight.

Comment: It is happening for react-native-gesture-handler. I had to stop the gestures in stack and drawer navigations. But I don't want to do that.

Comment: How did you configure the gesture handler? May I see your code?

Comment: I didn't configure the gesture handler in my code. It is used by react-navigation. When I run my code directly to my iPhone. The gesture handler works fine. But when I upload a build in the "app store connect" and download it using testflight app on my iphone. It do not work. I don't have any crash log. No way to find out why crashing it. In my app there is a drawer nav also. when I swipe left to right the app crashes. When I press back button in the stack nav header, then the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution after profiling the issue in xcode
this solution is work for me fine : 
https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/320#issuecomment-447534290